# Mapbox iOS setVisibleCoordinates not behaving as expected

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm having some trouble displaying a fixed map of Ireland using Mapbox in ios on different screen sizes. MGLMapView.setVisibleCoordinates seems to be what I need but it's not behaving as I'd expect. I'm expecting to pass in a bottom left coordinate and a top right coordinate and have that define a rectangle to display regardless of screen size.

`mapView.setVisibleCoordinates([CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.347676, longitude: -11.444362), CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 56.375322, longitude: -4.128659)], count: 2, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets.zero, animated: false)`

I've also tried

`mapView.setVisibleCoordinateBounds(MGLCoordinateBounds(sw: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.347676, longitude: -11.444362), ne: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 56.375322, longitude: -4.128659)), edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets.zero, animated: false)`

To the same results as shown below. As you can see the iphone 5s layout is perfect but I'm expecting the code above to show the same view on ipad however it is zoomed out too much. How can I show the same view across devices?

[image: IPad]

[image: Iphone 5s]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I got this working. There is a camera method on the MGLMapView that will return a camera that zooms as far in as it can while still displaying a rectangle you specify. Just have to make sure this is done in the `didFinishLoading` delegate method.

```
let northeast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.499130, longitude: -5.945938)
let southwest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.133369, longitude: -10.531064)

let ireland = MGLCoordinateBounds(sw: southwest, ne: northeast)

let camera = mapView.camera(mapView.camera, fitting: ireland, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets.zero)

mapView.setCamera(camera, animated: false)
```

Comment: That's a nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example on Mapbox's website that does exactly (I think) what you want. I've taken the liberty of inserting your coordinates, etc. as below. Links break so I'll post the code.

EDIT: Changed to disallow scrolling, panning and zooming.

```
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

    private var ireland: MGLCoordinateBounds!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.delegate = self


        let northeast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 56.375322, longitude: -4.128659)
        let southwest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.347676, longitude: -11.444362)

        var box = [northeast, southwest]
        mapView.setVisibleCoordinates(&box, count: 2, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 20.0, right: 20.0), animated: false)
        mapView.isScrollEnabled = false
        mapView.allowsZooming = false

        view.addSubview(mapView)
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite working but I get the theory. The ipad is still too zoomed out and the iphone is zoomed in too far. Could you share the link you got it from in a comment?

Comment: I think you got it from the "Restrict map panning to an area" tutorial. My map is not movable or zoomable at all so it should just be a fixed view showing Ireland. I'm still searching...

Comment: Ah okay, I did misunderstand. If you just want a static view of Ireland - no scrolling, no zooming it should just be a case of setting the view and the respective properties. I'll amend my answer. EDIT: Just checked on a test app and it works on both iPad and iPhone for me.

Answer (score 0):

This helps me to zoom particular region in Mapbox

```
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
self.mapView.zoomLevel = 13
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
self.mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long, animated: true)
```